# SSH - Find multiple files and delete them

Tags: ssh, putty

We have a bunch of old deprecated files that reside inside of 400 subdomain directories.

I'm trying to delete them out in 1 shot.

One of these old pages is called index1.php.  I was able to figure out the following in SSH to give me a list of all these files.

I did get a list, but not a count, which would be very helpful.

```
 find . -name index1.php
```

How do I go from this to make the server delete all these files it found with the name 'index1.php'

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the list of potential files you could delete...

`find . -name "index1.php"` - Are you absolutely sure you want to remove them?

If so, something like:

`find . -name "index1.php" -delete`

or

`find . -name "index1.php" -exec rm -f {} \;`

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I'm sure I want to remove these particular file.  What is the difference between the -delete option and the -exec rm option?  Do they offer different things?  Also, is it possible to get a count at the end to see how many were deleted?

Comment: Speed, efficiency... it's one thing if you have 400 files to delete... but if there are 40,000 files, a different approach could be taken. For file counts, maybe something like `find . -name "index1.php" | wc -l`

Comment: If you are deleting 40,000 files (or more), I recommend 'find . -name index1.php -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f' as being more efficient than -exec rm for large numbers of files.